# moved my RoR, jquerymobile, devise project to new computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, devise

I've been working on a Ruby on Rails, project at work. I installed rails on my home computer and moved the project folder from work to home but now I get all kinds of errors. when I start the server and go to localhost:3000 I get

> Template is missing Missing template home/index, application/index
>   with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
>   :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: *
>   "c:/Sites/devise/app/views" *
>   "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views"

Getting devise and jquerymobile set up with ruby on rails was difficult, am I going to have to start over from scratch again? I think I have the same rails versions installed.

EDIT: Heres how I did the transfer:

I had the project on my work computer in c:\sites\deviseproject. I copied the entire folder to my google drive. I came home installed rails from the railsinstaller.exe just like I did at work, I made a new project to make sure rails was working right, I copied the deviseproject folder to c:\sites\ I opened a command, ran the server, did bundle install, and tried to go to the websites. then I thought, well maybe I should run rake db so I did, rake db:migrate and it said,

> you have already activated rake 10.1.1, but your Gemfile requires rake
>   10.1.0 using bundle exec may solve this

So I ran bundle exec and it said

> Bundler: exec needs a command to run.

thats all I've done.

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Comment: try to run bundle install before running server

Comment: Can you describe your moving process, step by step? Bundler should have taken care of dependencies (it's what it was designed for).

Comment: Does that file it is complaining about exist?

Comment: I added the transfer process above. yes I did bundle install. the file that is the home page does exist; my routes file says 
`Deviseproject::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :dashboard
  root to: "home#index"
  end`
and I do have a home model and the index.html.erb is in the home folder in views, so the entire file structure has been preserved as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wrote your procedure chronologically:

> ran the server, did bundle install

Bundler needs to run first to install all of your app's dependencies, including the correct server.

- Kill server
- Run `bundle install`
- Restart server: `rails s`

The error message after attempting `rake db:migrate` indicates missing gems, specifically missing an expected version.

> bundle exec

Expects `bundle exec [command]`.

This wraps a command, giving it access to the gems in your bundle. It does nothing on it's own, hence "needs a command to run."

The error message suggested you use `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. However...

> rake db:migrate

Not necessary if using SQLite since it uses flat files stored in `/db`. Those got copied over with everything else so Rails saw no change to the database.

Comment: thanks, I stopped the server and tried this but it had no affect. thanks for the advice and help though! I really appreciate it!